# Считать из нескольких файлов в 1 dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Несколько файлов нужно считать в 1 dataframe и добавить колонку: пользователь - номер файла.

Мой код не работает:

```
s=glob.glob(r'capstone_user_identification/3users/*.csv', recursive=True)
totaldata=pd.read_csv(s[0]).loc[:,'user_id']=1
for filename in s[1:]:
    g=pd.read_csv(filename).loc[:,'user_id']=s[1:].index(filename)
    totaldata.append(g)
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно немного оптимизировать:

```
names = glob.glob(r'capstone_user_identification/3users/*.csv', recursive=True)

df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f).assign(user_id=i+1) for i,f in enumerate(names)],
               ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал так:

```
names = glob.glob(r'capstone_user_identification/3users/*.csv', recursive=True)

cont = []

for i in range(len(names)):
    # считать один датафрейм, добавить ему поле и сохранить
    df = pd.read_csv(names[i])
    df['user_id'] = i
    cont.append(df)

# объединить все датафреймы
totaldata = pd.concat(cont)
```